# Symfony Gedmo\Timestampable deletedAt

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, get

I have entity project and use Timestampable and when I create entity, I have datetime when create, when update I have datetime when update but when I delete I my entity delete in Data Base but and I don't have field deletedAt. I dont want delete entity I want only set deleted or how use deleted from Timestampable

```
/**
  * Project
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="project")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Repository\ProjectRepository")
  * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
  */
  class Project
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Type("integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"id", "level", "main_skill", "name"}, separator="-")
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 * @Expose()
 * @Type("string")
 */
protected $slug;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Expose()
 * @Type("string")
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Expose()
 * @Type("DateTime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $deletedAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
 */
protected $updatedAt;
```

this is my action

```
    /**
 * Deletes a Project entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_project_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 * @ParamConverter("entity", class="ArtelProfileBundle:Project")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($entity->getId());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_all_project'));
}

private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('admin_project_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
        ->getForm()
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're already using `Gedmo\Timestampable`, have a look at Gedmo [SoftDeleteable behaviour](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md). This behaviour does not only avoid the deletion of your entity, but stores the deletion timestamp in a field, like you requested.

Comment: What I need to do? I use 
        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
and my entity delete in my DB 
 I don’t understand how remove entity but not delete in data base just set deleteAt time how this solved for my task ?

Comment: If you set up `SoftDeletable` correctly, it should do exactly that for you. From the docs "SoftDeleteable behavior allows to "soft delete" objects, filtering them at SELECT time by marking them as with a timestamp, but not explicitly removing them from the database."

Answer (score 1):

I solved my task:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
orm:
    default:
        ...
        softdeleteable: true

doctrine:
...
orm:
    filters:
        softdeleteable:
            class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
            enabled: true
```

and add to etity @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")

```
/**
* Project
*
* @ORM\Table(name="project")
* @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Repository\ProjectRepository")
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class Project
{
/////
    /**
 * @var \DateTime $deletedAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $deletedAt;
}
```

and action

```
    /**
 * Deletes a Project entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_project_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 * @ParamConverter("entity", class="ArtelProfileBundle:Project")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($entity->getId());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_all_project'));
}
```

Then I have entity in my database and set deletedAt datetime